# Why should port number be converted to Network Byte Order when binding a socket?

Tags: c, sockets

I came across this snippet of code which appeared in the guts of setting up a socket:

```
#define PORT xxxx

struct sockaddr_in self;
self.sin_family = PF_INET;
self.sin_port = htons(PORT);
```

I understand that we need to convert byte order of the data that we are transmitting over a network to `Network Byte Order` but I don't get why we need to convert port number to that as well when setting up a socket. I mean, when we do bind, isn't it a "local" thing? Say the port we intend to be bound is 1 and the machine actually uses little endian; now since we converted it into Network Byte Order, wouldn't we be binding a totally different port to the socket?

Comment: Because that is the way that the socket API was originally defined by the Berkeley guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think let's assume you are using TCP. The port number is going to be in the packet header. That is going to be transmitted. So it will be in Network Byte Order.

Comment: But when doing bind, wouldn't it be interpreted differently because the port is totally reversed?

Comment: Socket is part of OS. But the OS could be run on any machine. Probably a big endian machine. When programming with sockets we shouldn't write machine-dependent code (but we cannot avoid it anyways), so we should write in Network Byte Order, which is machine-independent. IMO, it's just a definition.

Comment: A better design of the API would have been fully endian-neutral, so that the API's users didn't have to deal with it manually for every sockaddr_in.  But that isn't what happened, and now we are stuck with it for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, So do you guys mean that we should use network byte order for portability, even it means the sacrifice that on a little endian machine the port we are actually binding would be different than the original PORT macro?

Comment: @Xufeng you should write your code to use htons() as shown in your example, so that it will work the same on all machines.  (In an ideal world you wouldn't have to do that, but in our actual world you do)

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking why you the application programmer does it instead of the library doing it internally?  If so, the only technical advantage I can think of is that it allows the application to do the conversion once and cache it and use it many times without requiring many conversions.

On TCP you only need to use it once per connection and typically won't make millions of connections.  But on UDP you use it every time you send a packet, and it's reasonable to assume you'd make millions or billions of such calls.

Then, for myriad calls to say `sendto()` for UDP, or what have you, the re-ordered-if-necessary address is supplied to the OS which can copy it as-is directly into outgoing network packets.

The alternative of doing it in the kernel would require every call to `sendto()` to take what the app knows as the same address over and over, and reconvert it every time.

Since `sendto()` benefits from this, that was perhaps sufficient reason for them to have the rest of the API work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You transmit the port number over the network. It is a part of the IP packet for TCP. Look up the RFC (ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)

Comment: How about the second part of the question? How does bind recognize the port correctly if the port number is reversed after hton?

Answer (score 0):

The `struct sockaddr_in` is just a wrapper structure for `struct sockaddr`:

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short sa_family;
    char           sa_data[14];
};
```

The Port number and Ip-address are held together here. They are held together in `sa_data[14]`-  the first `2 bytes` holding the port number, and the next `4 bytes` holding the ip-address. The remaining `8 bytes` are unused. These are the `8 bytes` you clear to zeroes via `sin_zero[8]` when you use `sockaddr_in`.

This in entirety is sent via network, including the port number in network order.

Answer (score 0):

Machines can use different encodings little/big endian. To standardize that you should use a uniform encoding when communicating through the network. That's why you have to convert the encoding to Network Byte Order regardless of it being little/big endian, what matters is that it is uniform and it is understood correctly by every device and software in the network.